# How to cover unit test case for addEventListener in Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I got unit test passed but code coverage stuck at function not covered

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const menus = document.querySelectorAll('.menu-toggle');
    if (menus) {
      menus.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', _event => {
        el.parentElement?.classList.toggle('open')
      }));
    }
  }
```

so is there any way to do 100% code coverage

my unit test code : -

```
    const De: DebugElement = fixture.debugElement;

    const El: HTMLElement = De.nativeElement;

    El.innerHTML += '<li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-link menu-toggle"><i class="menu-icon tf-icons bx bx-dock-top"></i></a></li>'
    
    const menus = El.querySelectorAll('.menu-toggle')!;
  
      menus.forEach(menu  => {
        const parent = menu.parentElement;
        const x = menu as HTMLElement;
        expect(parent?.classList.contains('open')).toBeFalse();
        x.click();
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(parent?.classList.contains('open')).toBeTrue();           
      });
```

Comment: Which function is not covered?

Comment: _event function

Comment: Include the unit test code in the question, not here in the comments. It's barely readable

Comment: I am surprised that this test case works correctly. You are calling `ngAfterViewInit()` **before** creating the DOM structure. Could be that it only works by chance. You should call it **after** creating the DOM structure.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why are you using event listeners in Angular? You can use [event binding](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/event-binding) instead. Also you can use [class binding](https://angular.dev/guide/templates/class-binding) to apply custom classes. And [`*ngFor`](https://angular.dev/guide/directives#listing-items-with-ngfor) for repeating elements. What you implemented isn't really the Angular way. Or does the DOM come from an external non-Angular library?